# how is it possible to click through a position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100% overlay in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

i have a bug i'm trying to narrow down and it's proving to be a doozie. i'm making a modal overlay and in IE8 for some reason i am able to click "through", focus inputs and select text underneath it.

in IE9, FF, Chrome everything works as expected. unfortunately a reduced testcase i slapped together (shown below) works just fine in IE8. has anyone run into this bug before? hoping to save some time. thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                background: pink;
                position: fixed;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0.5;
                -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" />
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, i was using rgba() rather than opacity because i needed only the background to have transparency.

for IE it generated gradient filter using -ms-filter which was causing the issue. ended up just using

```
background: url(/images/EBEBEBB3.png);
background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is indeed that IE allows clicks to bleed through when the background of a div is transparent. For me, this works everywhere:

Just use a base64 encode of a 1x1 pixel transparent GIF as background, this stops all the clicks / taps (also tested on IE9 and IE8). Plus, this is pure CSS, no extra images needed.

```
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this issue is that IE does not consider semi-opaque backgrounds to be valid click targets, and so clicks are passed through to the element underneath.

For IE, you must have a solid color background or a background image to have an element capture clicks. As you've discovered, filters will not work.

The common thing to do is to use a 1x1 transparent GIF as the background-image for IE. The element will then capture clicks appropriately.