# How to prevent event leaking through an overlaying element in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overlay

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="with-shield">
    <div class="shield"></div>
    <input type="radio"/>
</div>
​
```

... and CSS:

```
.with-shield {
  position: relative;   
}

.shield {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;   
  z-index: 100;
}
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyHzZ/1)).

FireFox and Chrome do no let you click the radio button (as the `.shield` is positioned over the top of it), however IE9 (and I assume older versions) does (even though developer tools shows `.shield` is correctly in place).

How can I change the CSS to let `.shield` absorb click events (i.e. to stop a user being able to select the radio) in IE?​

I need this as I'm presenting the results of a customer survey to employees, simply by redisplaying the form view; I want to add an overlay to stop the employees changing values accidentally (I've already disabled `tabIndex` etc).

Comment: set a z-index for the shield.

Comment: @EvanLarsen: [already tried that](http://jsfiddle.net/AyHzZ/1/); question updated to reflect.

Comment: you might have an easier time making the input disabled http://jsfiddle.net/AyHzZ/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how is it possible to click through a position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100% overlay in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808643/how-is-it-possible-to-click-through-a-position-fixed-height-100-width-100)

Comment: @RyanErickson: But then the input field is grayed out and hard to see.

Comment: @j08691: ah, that seems like a good enough duplicate... didn't come across that one when I searched.

Answer (score 14):

And even later to the party, but this is what I did:

Just use a base64 encode of a 1x1 pixel transparent GIF as background, this stops all the clicks / taps (also tested on IE9 and IE8).

```
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
```

Comment: This works great. A benefit to using this over the others is it still allows child components to have opacity.

Comment: Fantastic! Perfect Fix.  Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Great fix, works both for IE10 as well as for IE9! Thanks a lot Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem recently. Muthu Kumaran's is great, except that it did not account IE < 8. Here is how you can do it:

```
.with-shield {
  position: relative;   
}

.shield {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;   
  z-index: 100;

background-color:#fff;
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 001);

}
```

Unfortunately neither jsfiddle nor jsbin are running properly on IE8 so I can show you, but I created a test page in my local machine and tested and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but do something like this:

```
#BlockAction{bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; z-index: -1;}  
#BlockAction.Blocked{z-index: 1000; cursor:wait;background-color:#fff;opacity:0}
```

The background colour and opacity will cater for IE9 allowing transparent background clicks to go through. Other browsers catch the click without it.